# Create a new section on the grid (new form)

Tags: module, magento-1, adminhtml, grid

I have a basic grid with edit and save:

```
Module
├── Block
│   ├── Adminhtml
│   │   ├── Stores
            ├── Edit
                ├── Form.php
            ├── Grid.php
            ├── Edit.php
        ├── Stores.php
├── controllers
    ├── Adminhtml
        ├── StoresController.php
```

I want to add a button that will load another form. So insider Store.php I added the button:

```
$this->_addButton('import_store',
            array(
                'label'     => 'Import CSV',
                'onclick'   => "setLocation('{$this->getUrl('*/stores/importfile')}')",
                'class'     => 'add',
            )
        );
```

and inside `StoresController.php` I started a new method for `Module_Adminhtml_StoresController`:

```
public function importfileAction()
    {
       ... 
    }
```

But I am stuck now and don't know how to proceed.

When clicking on the `Import CSV` button you should go to a new form where you can upload a file. How should I proceed with the grid?

Thank you!

Comment: have you need file save code in StoresController.php?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your question

Answer (score 1):

Add a form - read one of the many blog articles how to do it.

Then you can load this form using your controller `importfileAction` and handle the upload e.g. in `importfilePostAction`